# The collapsed navigation bar button is not expanding when clicked in CodePen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

CodePen link: http://codepen.io/mraduldubey/pen/OMmzYV?editors=100
Here is the navigation bar's code. This collapsed button expands in Tryit Editor of w3cschools website but doesn't expand in CodePen:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header" >
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mradul Dubey</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Mind sharing the codepen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306573/bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not referencing the jquery, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css in your code. Here is your code on jsfiddle and codepen...

[JSFiddle](https://goo.gl/baxAff)
[CodePen](http://goo.gl/MqqiVo)

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Are you saying that my pen doesn't work, or are you copying my code over to a new pen?

Comment: Your code is working fine in JSFiddle. Not in CodePen. No, I'm not copying it.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chromium@Ubuntu15.10

Comment: Do you have windows or mac. Try it on that and see if it works. Ubuntu isn't ideal.