# dropdown on bootstrap navbar not working properly

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar. And it is being used on many pages. So I have created one navbar.php and It contains the elements of the navbar.
I am including it on all the pages. But the dropdown part of the navbar is not functioning properly. It is not taking me to the desired page. All the links that are refering to home.php is working. The dropdown for login also works. But when I click on it it does not take me to the login.php or masterlogin.php
What could be the problem?

**navbar.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php"><img src="logo3.png" alt="Home"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="home.php#content1">Content1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="home.php#content2">Content2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="home.php#content3">Content3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="home.php#content4">Content4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="home.php#content5">Content5</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">LOGIN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="masterlogin.php">MASTER LOGIN</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.php**

```
<!--At the top-->
<?php
include_once "navbar.php";
?>
<!-- Followed by rest of the code for home.php-->
```

Comment: Maybe forgot to add the javascript?

Comment: the javascript is also there. Forgot to add it to my question. Sorry. But still it is not working.

Comment: Try adding `role="navigation"` to the <nav /> node. See source at [bootstrap themes](http://themes.getbootstrap.com/products/application)

Comment: No sir. Added role="navigation". It still is not working.

Comment: Can you create [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I will have to do too much of editing to create a JSFiddle. the css and javascript I am using is basic bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js. Nothing more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306573/bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

replace your css js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

it's working in your code

Comment: Yip, I never saw the wrong order of... jQuery first... `if("undefined"==typeof jQuery)throw new Error("Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery");` Weird that he didn't get that message...?