# Not found button navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The navbar toggle button appears on mobile but does not work. I can not find the reasoning behind the navbar toggle to not work.

The navbar works in bootply but it does not work with the php code. The file path is set well and the routes online code and it does not work either.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; />
    <title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['user_email']; ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>

    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RowApp</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="upload_trainer.php">Subir entreno</a></li>
                <li><a href="remeros/alta_remero.php">Remeros</a></li>
                <li><a href="remeros/historial_remero.php">Historial remeros</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; <?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php?logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp; Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top:150px;text-align:center;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:35px;">
        <a href="http://www.codingcage.com/">Coding Cage - Programming Blog</a><br /><br />
        <p>REMEROS</p>

        <?php


    echo "<span style='color: blue;'>Extracción de todas las filas ...</span>";


        ?>



    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306573/bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's script should be placed after jQuery one.