# bootstrap site won't scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am making a portfolio webpage on codepen.io . Everything was going fine until now as my page has simply stopped scrolling and I can't find a solution/identity the piece of code that caused the page to stop scrolling.
HERE IS MY CODE:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.intro-text {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#About {
  height: 500px;
}
#Portfolio {
  height: 500px;
}
#Social {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Ray Fitzgerald</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">button
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#About">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfollio</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Social">Social</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Main Body & Text Items -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="intro-text" id="About">
          My name is Ray Fitzgerald and I am a young Programmer and Web Developer
        </div>
        <div class="intro-text" id="Portfolio">
          Portfolio
        </div>
        <div class="intro-text" id="Social">
          Social
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why does the navbar contain the entire web site?

Comment: Since it's already on CodePen, could you link a live example?

Comment: If you have `navbar-fixed-top` with nothing under it how do you plan on scrolling anywhere?

Comment: See these links for your mobile nav to function: [What's Included Dox](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included) and [Bootstrap Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306573/bootstrap-navbar) and you haven't included `<div class="navbar-header">` which you will probably want, See [Navbar Dox](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `<!-- Main Body & Text Items -->` out of the `navbar-fixed-top` `<nav>` element.

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/85qLh41a/2/

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Ray Fitzgerald</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">button
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#About">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfollio</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Social">Social</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
   <!-- Main Body & Text Items -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="intro-text" id="About">
          My name is Ray Fitzgerald and I am a young Programmer and Web Developer
        </div>
        <div class="intro-text" id="Portfolio">
          Portfolio
        </div>
        <div class="intro-text" id="Social">
          Social
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: a yes this worked and makes perfect sense. Thanks very much. Any idea also why my collapse menu button does not work when i reduce the size of the window? its unresponsive. https://codepen.io/RayFitzgerald/full/vKgYoj/

Comment: @RayFitzgerald I am getting off right now, I would suggest making another question asking about that.