# Bootstrap Collapse not working, but works in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started working with bootstrap and came across an issue when trying to use "Collapse".

I am 99% sure I have the Javascript linked correctly because the reference to the css also works. I have also tried to replace it with the CDN

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

but it still didn't work.

As I was placing my code into JSfiddle to share on here, I tested it, and it worked from there and I can't figure out why.

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9xjvonq/)

To find the collapse button, just shrink your browser's size until you see the 3 bars in the top right. That is the button that is supposed to display the rest of the nav when clicked.

Other notes: I am using codeigniter, which is why you will see some PHP in this code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Navbar. When I press the button nothing happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306573/bootstrap-navbar-when-i-press-the-button-nothing-happens)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include  `jquery.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.js'); ?>" ></script> <!--Boostrap Javascript -->

</head>
```

Bootstrap JS requires JQuery to work and thus you need to include it **before** `bootstrap.min.js` in your script tag.

Comment: Awesome. Always something simple. Thank you so much, I'll accept the answer when it allows me to. Can I ask why this is an issue?

Comment: @Ddrossi93 I edited the answer for the explaination.